# Binding gridview using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have gridview and i used stored procedure in backend . The issue is i have not used any textbox or label only gridview.

When i run my code, It shows a compilation error that spproduct1 expects parameter @id which is  expected not supplied. 
Can you please fix the error

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page

{

  string _strsql = string.Empty;

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

  {

   string cs = ("Data Source=172.16.6.173;Initial Catalog=servion_hari;User  ID=sa;Password=Servion@123");

   _strsql = "select * from tblproduct where id=@id and Name=@Name and  Description=@Description";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spgetproducts1", con);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int.ToString());

    id.Value = GridView1.ToString();


    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


     con.Close();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;

     GridView1.DataBind();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parameters are always added to SqlCommand. Search about SqlCommand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a value to a parameter defined in your query you can use the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GridView1.ToString());
```

for a better implementation:

1. try to put all database related functions in a separate file and call them in your form.
2. define an stored procedure over your database and call it via C# code. this way of using stored procedure is poor

**Edited**

step1:
declare your stored procedure on your database like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_PRODUCTS_SP]
    /*Type of this variables should be their column types*/
    @id int,
    @name varchar(MAX),
    @description varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tblproduct] 
    WHERE id=@id AND 
          Name=@name AND 
          Description=@description
END
```

step 2: call the stored procedure like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
String conStr = "Data Source=172.16.6.173;Initial Catalog=servion_hari;User  ID=sa;Password=Servion@123";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("GET_PRODUCTS_SP", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", yourIdValue);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", yourNameValue);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", yourDescriptionValue);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
try
{
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    con.Close();
}
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

https://studio.youtube.com/video/Aqoq_5teKtY/edit?utm_campaign=upgrade&utm_medium=redirect&utm_source=%2Fmy_videos

Comment: I edit my solution and suggest you to implement your store procedure using it :)

Comment: @hari: can you show how you passed value to parameters "@id", "@name", "@description" ?

Comment: @Dev You are asking my SP or Frontend coding

Comment: @hari yeah from your Frontend.

Comment: @Dev  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            String conStr = "Data Source=172.16.6.173;Initial Catalog=servion_hari;user=sa;password=Servion@123";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            
            _strsql = "select * from tblproduct where id=@id and Name=@Name and Description=@Description";

Comment: @hari how you written these : com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", yourIdValue); com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", yourNameValue); com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", yourDescriptionValue);

Answer (score 5):

For Stored Procedure way:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spgetproducts1", con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //first paramenter: parameter name, second parameter: parameter value of object type
        //using this way you can add more parameters
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GridView1.ToString());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Question; What your are trying to achieve with GridView1.ToString() ?

Comment: @hari how you written these : 

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", yourIdValue);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", yourNameValue);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", yourDescriptionValue);

Answer (score 0):

you are missing

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(id);
```

to add your `@id` parameter before executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because you just declare the SqlParameter without assign it into your SqlCommand.

```
SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int.ToString());

id.Value = GridView1.ToString();
```

change to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", GridView1.ToString()));
```

Question : what is your GridView1.ToString()? What are you suppose to assign to ?

Comment: Actually i have a backend database with some datas , i need to retrieve the data and store in cache and retrieve the data for next 15 min whoever access the site. So i am planning this with gridview , is there any suggestions

Comment: gridview use to store a set of data, you need to keep ur id, name, Description at somewhere, you cannot just use GridView1.ToString(). So even you corrected the @id assignment, you will hit another error on the name and description

Answer (score -4):

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    viewrecord s = new viewrecord();
    s.std_id = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
    SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connstring);
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("viewrecord", conn2);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@std_id", s.std_id);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ErrorMsgBoxBack.aspx");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn2.Close();
    }
```

}

Comment: How does this solve the problem in the question? While it might be code that looks like it applies to something similar, it appears to have been copy-&-pasted from some other project that is not directly related to this question. It would be much better if you edited the code such that it relates directly to the code in the question.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.